# Does battery state-of-charge affect regenerative braking in electric vehicles?

Tags: batteries, electric-vehicles

Most battery-electric vehicles support regenerative braking, where energy is sent back into the battery. Does the battery state-of-charge (percentage charged) affect how much energy is recovered in regenerative braking, and if so, is there an optimal state-of-charge for maximizing the effect of regenerative braking?

Comment: +1. Great article here that looks at the effect of regenerative braking on battery degradation, and should have some answers. I'll take a look when I have more time. ["Impact of Dynamic Driving Loads and Regenerative Braking on the Aging of Lithium-Ion Batteries in Electric Vehicles"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/2.0801713jes)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does, especially on the "1-pedal driving" cars that lack the proper hardware to use brake pedal for braking, but rather they automatically slow down when the gas pedal is released.

Tesla electric vehicles can disable regenerative braking due to three reasons:

- Battery is very cold (as in freezing)
- Battery is full
- Car driver disabled regenerative braking or reduced its strength to half (good for driving on snow or ice with 1-pedal driving cars, because the automatic slowdown can be too rapid and the car can spiral out of control if releasing the gas pedal and the regenerative braking strength hasn't been reduced)

For these Tesla vehicles, the car driver will immediately notice the effect: the car no longer slows down automatically. This may even be dangerous if the driver is used to automatic slowdown. I believe there is a warning on the display about these conditions that modify the auto-slowdown effect.

For cars that have proper hardware to distribute force between regenerative braking, possibly engine braking, and brake pads, such as Toyota vehicles, then it will use other means of braking than regenerative braking automatically such as engine braking or brake pads. The car driver doesn't notice this. All it means is that the brake energy isn't being regenerated but rather wasted via engine or brake pads.

Toyota hybrids on mountainous areas automatically shift to engine braking once the battery is full, so you won't overheat your disc brakes even though you press the brake pedal to slow down on descents. Purely electric vehicles can't do this engine braking.

In practice, you always use more battery charge than you gain by braking, so nearly all of the time there is room for regenerative braking in the battery. Therefore, unless you live on top of a mountain, regular use will mean all energy will be regenerated (sans a small efficiency loss). If you live on top of a mountain, then you shouldn't charge to 100% to allow regenerative braking to work on the descent but you probably won't do that anyway since 100% charge reduces battery shelf life.

About the optimal state of charge, NiMH batteries are about 99% efficient when charging to 70% and after that the efficiency reduces. However, NiMH batteries aren't used in electric cars, only in non-plug-in hybrids, and they anyway operate always below 70% state of charge (even if the display indicates it's full that means 70% full). Lithium ion is very efficient to practically full charge so there isn't an optimal state of charge unless the battery is so full it no longer accepts any charge.